# Repeat Image from Storyboard for Launch Screen

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

All the ways I can see to tile/repeat an image either onto a UIView or UIImage all include some Swift code, however I can't use Swift on the Launch Screen. How can I use a pattern image that I need to repeat horizontally and vertically across the entire UIView?